Identify this set: bags containing pirate parts
I got 2 sealed bags labeled 2011 Lego group and the bag numbers #2 and #3  to unknown set and have a fair few dozen sets and can't recall which they are for and misplaced box's and instructions...
I know they belong to a 2011 build as some kind Pirate set as there is a canon and Pirate hat and a shark that can tell is in the bags...
Just unsure which set?
If could please help source out in which set # they belong too would be totally appreciated and massive help ?

enter image description here


You didn't upload the photographs right - have a look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344851/how-do-you-add-a-screenshot-image-to-your-stack-overflow-post

Ok thanks Will do

That's set 70807 "MetalBeard's Duel" - I hinted this from the pirate parts mixed with technic cogs and ball joints.

This is confirmed by part 11305 "Hero Factory blade with curved tip" in silver, which only appears in nine sets including this one.
Also note that the bags are labelled "2011" because the bags themselves were made in 2011. They were sitting in a warehouse for three years until they were used to pack the parts for the MetalBeard set, which was released in 2014. Markings in plastic bags never provide useful information for set identification.

Thank you kindly
